# Is it safe to use window.open(param,'_blank') by passing in the params during onClick in react to open a page in new tab?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an anchor tag that has an onClick method on it, which gets passed in the event and parameter. The parameter is for example "https://www.google.com"

What is it for? User lands on the main page where they will log in and see "web apps" they are authenticated to use. Once logged in, they will click one of the apps to go to the respective page, in doing so, the credentials will be shared with that page so they don't have to log in again.

The issue: As I build this main portal I am using an onClick tied to the anchor tags to pass in the event and parameter and inside "this.handleSubmit" I am doing window.open(param,'_blank'). Is this safe to do? What potential issues am I facing?

**EDIT added code**

My stateful component:

```js
<div class={`row ${classes["appcard-row-style"]}`}>
          <div class={`col-sm ${classes["appcard-col-style"]}`}>
            <AppCard app-link="https://www.google.com" name="App" linkClick={this.handleSubmit}/>
          </div>
          <div class={`col-sm ${classes["appcard-col-style"]}`}>
            <AppCard app-link="#" name="coming soon" linkClick={this.handleSubmit}/>
          </div>
          <div class={`col-sm ${classes["appcard-col-style"]}`}>
            <AppCard app-link="#" name="coming soon" linkClick={this.handleSubmit}/>
          </div>
        </div>
```

my stateless component:

```js
<div class={`card text-center ${classes["card-main-style"]}`}>
        <img
          class="card-img-top"
          src="https://imgplaceholder.com/420x320/ff7f7f/333333/fa-image"
          alt="Card image cap"
        />
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">{this.props.name}</h5>
          <a href={this.props["app-link"]}  class="btn btn-primary" onClick={(e)=>linkClick(e,this.props["app-link"])}>
            Go to link
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: It would be much easier to help if you attempted some code to see what happens. It's really not clear what you're asking.

Comment: @Pointy updated main with code! thanks

Comment: Well there's nothing "unsafe" about calling `window.open()`.  Does it work?  Is anything happening that you don't want to happen?

Comment: @Pointy yes it works, but what i am concerned about is the window.open part. Am I opening access to the window object by calling this?

Comment: No.  If you load a page from a different domain, it's "firewalled" from your content just as your code is firewalled from it's content.